# Laravel multiple observers and Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, logic

I have a strange requirement and trying to handle it. We have a table `TableA` and a connected API webhook that updates items in `TableA`. If something value in table `A` is changed by webhook, a Job is dispatched, say `JobA`. This is triggered in the model observer `ObserverA` and in `saved` method, checking if the value changed using `wasChanged` and value equals X

So far so good.

Now we have another table `TableB` which is connected to the same API service as A, but store different items than in `TableA`. We also have a logic to dispatch `JobB` when value using webhook changes. It also has the ability to dispatch `JobA` if some value changed. This is achieved through the same logic as above with an observer `ObserverB`.

Everything works so far.

Now we have a Logic to trigger `JobA` **only once** when the value changes either in `TableA` or in `TableB` or when the value changed both in `TableA`  and `TableB`.

The problem is currently, it dispatches two `JobA` if there are changes in both `TableA`  and `TableB`. What would be the perfect solution to handle this?

Comment: It is difficult to tell what your issue is because this is too abstract. You say this: "It also has the ability to dispatch JobA if some value changed" What value is changing that triggers this? Does this mean that something in Table A is being changed by the api call for Table B, and that is why JobA is triggered? If not, what is JobA doing that an api call to TableB triggers it?

Comment: If JobA is being triggered 2x because of the Event Observer which triggers it based on a field change which happens via EndpointB, this might fix the issue: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#saving-a-single-model-without-events